# Isset not working is always false on undefined in PHP JQuery Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data via an AJAX call with an id as parameter.
I check if there is an id in the url or not.

Example 1: My url looks like this with no id: `testurl`

Example 2:My url looks like this with an id: `testurl?pid=1000`

In my PHP isset if there is an id it should run some code and if there is no id it should run some other code. Right now it is always false.

When I echo the id in my php it prints undefined in the first example and it prints the id number in the second example as it should? The isset doesn't recognize the undefined value is always false.

JQuery:

```
 var url = window.location.href;

    // If there is an id in url retrieve it
    if(url.indexOf("=") > -1){
        var pid = url.split("=").pop();
    }


 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'testurl&pid=' + pid,
                data: $('#productform').serialize(),
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
```

PHP:

```
    public function saveTestProduct()
    {

        $pid =  $_GET['pid'];


        // Create and populate an object.

        echo $pid;

        // if there is an id run this code
        if (isset($_GET['pid'])){

        }else{
        // problem: this code is always executed even though there is an id
        }
```

Comment: Typo: `&pid=` should be `?pid=`

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a post via Ajax and you're trying to access the property via the global GET parameter. To fix your code, you can change the global to $_POST or change the ajax request method to 'get'

```
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'testurl?pid=' + pid,
                data: $('#productform').serialize(),
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
```

OR

```
       // if there is an id run this code
        if (isset($_POST['pid'])){

        }else{
        // problem: this code is always executed even though there is an id
        }
```

Also as Barmar said, make sure to update the typo to ?pid= rather than &pid=

Comment: I tried that but then the AJAX call doesn't work anymore. &pid= is the correct syntax for my CMS

Comment: Then access the global as a $_POST as shown in my second option

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the problem still persists.

Comment: Please dont tell me that 'testurl' is your actual url

Comment: No I changed that for this purpose. I don't understand whats wrong. I send the id to my php file. It echoes it correctly. Is var aid = undefined a string? and thats why Isset doens't recognize it?